# Change tableview datasource with two UIButtons

Tags: iphone, uibutton, ios5, uitableview

having a UITableView and its data source is an NSMutableArray which is actually an parsed XML file; In the same view I have two UIButtons with the same action method, how I'm able to toggle the tableview's datasource?

When pressing A button to load dataSource1 and B to load dataSource2

```
- (void)buttonsAction: (id)sender {
    
    BOOL activateSecond = _firstButton.selected;
    _firstButton.selected = !activateSecond;
    _secondButton.selected = activateSecond;
}

    dataSource1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    nodecontent = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        
    NSString *xmlURL = @"http://mydomain.com/file.xml";
    NSData *xmlData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:xmlURL]];
    xmlParserObject = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
    [xmlParserObject setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParserObject parse];
    [xmlData release];
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1 : load data into your arrays ( if you are fetching from xml/web do that, I have implemented static here )

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.arOne=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sagar",@"Amit",@"Nimit",@"Paresh",@"Rakesh",@"Yogesh", nil];
    self.arTwo=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Supreeth",@"Deepthy",@"Ankit",@"Sandeep",@"Gomathy", nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

step 2 : place conditional coding for tableViewCell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[(self.btnTapped.selected)?self.arTwo:self.arOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

step 3 : connect an action to your button ( here button is named as `btnTapped` )

```
- (IBAction)btnTitle:(id)sender {
    self.btnTapped.selected=!self.btnTapped.selected;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post! My case its more complicated but I think I'll have the problem solved by the end of the day

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4614/discussion-between-sugar-and-el-severo)

Answer (score 0):

When you click second button , remove all the  elements from your data source arrays like

```
[dataSource1 removeAllObjects];
```

And then parse the xml and add data to these arrays and when parsing get finished reload your tableView by doing

```
[tbl reloadData];
```

Hope it helps....

Comment: for nodecontent which is an NSMutableArray it says that 'removeAllObjects' may not respond...